# Log4J2 dynamic appender doesn't work with maven-shade-plugin

Tags: java, maven, log4j2

I add an appender programmatically. It was working until I added `maven-shade-plugin`. I wonder what makes my appender fail.

The appender works ✅ or not ❌ in these scenarios:

1. ✅ From IDE (IntelliJ IDEA)
2. ❌ With the shade (Uber/fat) jar <-- now works ✅ see answer
3. ✅ With separate jars (app jar, log4j jars)
4. ❌ With the app jar, and the log4j jars unzipped into a folder
5. ✅ With the app jar, and the log4j folder re-zipped

#### Sample project

- https://github.com/fmaylinch/log4j2-thread-context
- Here's the point where I add the custom appender:
  [ThreadContextFileLogHandler.java#L79](https://github.com/fmaylinch/log4j2-thread-context/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/ThreadContextFileLogHandler.java#L79)
- When the appender fails, it's because it doesn't receive the events here: [ThreadContextFileLogHandler.java#L156](https://github.com/fmaylinch/log4j2-thread-context/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/ThreadContextFileLogHandler.java#L156)

#### Reproduce scenarios with the sample project above

```bash
mvn clean compile
mkdir -p local/log4j-jars
unzip $HOME/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.17.2/log4j-api-2.17.2.jar -d local/log4j-jars
unzip -o $HOME/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.17.2/log4j-core-2.17.2.jar -d local/log4j-jars
cd local/log4j-jars
zip -r ../log4j-jars.zip .
cd ../..

# Scenario 2 ❌ uses fat jar
java -cp "target/log4j-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" org.example.Main

# Scenario 3 ✅ uses separate jars
java -cp "target/original-log4j-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.17.2/log4j-core-2.17.2.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.17.2/log4j-api-2.17.2.jar" org.example.Main

# Scenario 4 ❌ uses log4j files unzipped
java -cp "target/original-log4j-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:local/log4j-jars" org.example.Main

# Scenario 5 ✅ uses log4j files re-zipped
java -cp "target/original-log4j-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:local/log4j-jars.zip" org.example.Main
```

### Extra notes

In the scenario 5, I have noticed that I can remove some files in `META-INF`, but for my appender to work, I need to keep the following:

- `META-INF`

  - `org` (contains `Log4j2Plugins.dat`)
  - `services` (without this, the app even crashes)
  - `versions`
  - `MANIFES.MF`

#### Related questions

- [log4j2 JsonTemplateLayout not working with maven shade plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230924/log4j2-jsontemplatelayout-not-working-with-maven-shade-plugin) - this seems to be a problem with `Log4j2Plugins.dat`, but in my project there's only one file, in `log4j2-core`.
- [is there any diff between run a java program with jar or with a package unpacked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677674/is-there-any-diff-between-run-a-java-program-with-jar-or-with-a-package-unpacked) - according to my problem, there IS a difference (maybe the `META-INF` folder is not processed like in a jar)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [failing to load log4j2 while running fatjar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361052/failing-to-load-log4j2-while-running-fatjar)

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thanks so much for your comment. It didn't solve my problem but it leaded me to some useful information. I will post the solution I found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `maven-shade-plugin` is that it breaks the manifest of the original jars and overwrites important resources. I find the [`spring-boot-maven-plugin`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-repackage) much more useful and it can be also used by applications that don't use Spring at all.

The `maven-shade-plugin` in the context of Log4j requires a minimal configuration as [in this question](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/1386#issuecomment-1481686029):

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-transform-maven-shade-plugin-extensions</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <configuration>
    <transformers>
      <transformer implementation="org.apache.logging.log4j.maven.plugins.shade.transformer.Log4j2PluginCacheFileTransformer"/>
      <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
      <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
        <manifestEntries>
          <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
        </manifestEntries>
      </transformer>
    </transformers>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This configuration takes care of:

- **merging** `Log4j2Plugins.dat` files. Without `Log4j2PluginCacheFileTransformer` you can not use additional component libraries except `log4j-api` and `log4j-core`,
- **merging** service files. Without `ServiceResourceTransformer` you'll lose additional component like property sources,
- marking the JAR as multi-release jar: some classes used to gather caller's information were replaced in JDK 11. Therefore some Log4j classes have two versions (JDK 8 and JDK 9+). If you don't mark the JAR as multi-release, it will not work on JDK 11+.

**Edit:** All these problems with the `maven-shade-plugin` sum up to one: every time two jars have a file with the same name, it must be somehow merged.

That is why I prefer the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`: instead of breaking multiple jars and adding their files into a single archive, it adds the original jars to the archive. The exact structure of the resulting jar is described in [executable Jar format](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html).

The usage is straightforward: just add the `repackage` goal to your build and remove `maven-shade-plugin`.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will effectively add the small [`spring-boot-loader`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-loader) to your application. Version 2.x of the library requires Java 8, while version 3.x requires Java 17.

Comment: Could you add an example of `spring-boot-maven-plugin`? Does it have the problem with `Log4j2Plugins.dat`. Is it anyway necessary to use `Log4j2PluginCacheFileTransformer`?

Answer (score 2):

After more investigation, I added a new commit to the sample project [log4j2-thread-context](https://github.com/fmaylinch/log4j2-thread-context) with the fixes, so now it works fine.

I also added another fix related to `Log4j2Plugins.dat` (see [failing to load log4j2 while running fatjar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361052/failing-to-load-log4j2-while-running-fatjar)), that I didn't mention in my question.

In summary:

- I add the required `Multi-Release` entry to `MANIFEST.MF` using `ManifestResourceTransformer`.
- I copy the correct `Log4j2Plugins.dat` using `IncludeResourceTransformer`.

Maybe someone can explain about the `Multi-Release` entry.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <filters>
            <!-- Ignore these files, we will write the right one below -->
            <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/Log4j2Plugins.dat</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
        </filters>
        <transformers>
            <!--
              Copies the right Log4j2Plugins.dat file.
              You need a copy of the right Log4j2Plugins.dat file from log4j2-core into src/main/resources.
              You can get that file with these commands:
                log4j2_version=2.17.2
                rm src/main/resources/Log4j2Plugins-*.dat
                unzip -j $HOME/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/${log4j2_version}/log4j-core-${log4j2_version}.jar META-INF/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/Log4j2Plugins.dat -d src/main/resources
                mv src/main/resources/Log4j2Plugins.dat src/main/resources/Log4j2Plugins-${log4j2_version}.dat
            -->
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                <resource>META-INF/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/Log4j2Plugins.dat</resource>
                <file>src/main/resources/Log4j2Plugins-${log4j2.version}.dat</file>
            </transformer>

            <!-- Adds the Multi-Release entry in MANIFEST.MF -->
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
                </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
        </transformers>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

About `Log4j2Plugins.dat`, an alternative to `IncludeResourceTransformer` is filtering all the versions except the one in `log4j-core`. For example:

```xml
<filter>
    <artifact>io.github.technologize:*</artifact>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/Log4j2Plugins.dat</exclude>
    </excludes>
</filter>
<!-- filter other artifacts if needed -->
```

I don't like either solution because:

- If you add a copy of the file, you need to update it in case you update Log4j2. You may use this [3rd party plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36469245/1121497), but then you rely on a 3rd party plugin.
- If you add filters, you need to modify them in case you modify the dependencies (e.g. maybe you add a new dependency that contains another version of this `dat` file).

Comment: The `Log4j2Plugins.dat` files need to be **merged**. Removing a copy of `Log4j2Plugins.dat` prevents Log4j from discovering the plugins contained in that jar. You might as well remove the jar itself.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thanks so much for your answer. My solution works too, but maybe because I am not using classes from other `Log4j2Plugins.dat` files. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: I am sure it works to some extent, but it prevents you from using all the Log4j 2.x plugins on the classpath. BTW: Eduard's transformer has been donated to Log4j project a while ago (cf. [PR #2](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j-tools/pull/2)), we just didn't have the time to publish it yet. We should be able to do it soon.