# Log4j2 attemts to load a class that no longer exists

Tags: java, maven, log4j2

I am building a Java application using Maven. I recently added Log4j2 libraries (log4j-api and log4j-core) to the dependencies in my pom.xml file. This enables me to perform decent logging on my application.

Unfortunately, since adding those libraries, my application doesn't run properly. I am seeing the following every time I start it:

```
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
WARN StatusConsoleListener No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
```

I do have a log4j.xml file available to the application, so I must conclude that the missing getCallerClass is causing the failure to find it. What bothers me, however, is the fact that when looking on the Internet to discover the reason for the failure, I discovered that the sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass has been removed from the JDK since Java 8. Since I am using Java 17, and my dependencies are all compatible with Java 17 (including the log4j libraries that are V2.20.0), they shouldn't even be attempting to load sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass at all!

I have seen plenty of documentation explaining how the sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported in Java 8+, but I have been unable to get any coherent information on why log4j2 keeps insisting on attempting to load this class or how to prevent it from doing so. Can someone give some idea how I might stop log4j2 from attempting to load this class???

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.

It turns out that the log4j library versions were *not* the most recent. Afer checking the repositories, I upgraded log4j-api and log4j-core from V2.20.0 to V2.22.0. I do not understand why, but doing this has eliminated the getCallerClass warnings.

Answer (score 1):

In order to support all LTS Java version, `log4j-api` is a multi-release JAR. If your runtime or build environment does not supports MRJs (e.g. you shade all JARs into one, cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75996306/11748454)) the warning:

```
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
```

will appear.

Newer versions of `log4j-api` didn't change that. Only the warning message was updated to reflect the most common cause for the problem (cf. [PR #1760](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/1760)):

```
WARNING: Runtime environment or build system does not support multi-release JARs. This will impact location-based features.
```

Previously the most common cause was using JREs different from OpenJDK (e.g. Android).

**Remark**: The other warning message:

```
WARN StatusConsoleListener No Log4j 2 configuration file found.
  Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations.
  Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging.
  See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
```

has nothing to do with the first warning. You just need to name your configuration file properly (`log4j2.xml` instead of `log4j.xml`).