Startup log4j2 ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier and format specifier
In a project using maven,
I have the same issue as described in log4j2 ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier. But the problem persist even after implementing both solutions described in the answer to that question. i.e. exclude Log4jPlugins.dat and use the manifest transformer plugin for log4j.
Moreover I can confirm that the Jar file does not contain a file name Log4j2Plugins.dat nor under META-INF nor anywhere else in the jar tree structure.
Error message:

2024-06-22T00:41:49.937Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [d]                                                     
2024-06-22T00:41:49.952Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
2024-06-22T00:41:49.953Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [thread]                                              
2024-06-22T00:41:49.953Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
2024-06-22T00:41:49.954Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [level]                                              
2024-06-22T00:41:49.954Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
2024-06-22T00:41:49.954Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [logger]                                              
2024-06-22T00:41:49.954Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
2024-06-22T00:41:49.955Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [msg]                                                 
2024-06-22T00:41:49.955Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
2024-06-22T00:41:49.955Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [n]                                                   
2024-06-22T00:41:49.956Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
2024-06-22T00:41:49.964Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [d]                                                   
2024-06-22T00:41:49.964Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
2024-06-22T00:41:49.964Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [thread]    
2024-06-22T00:41:49.965Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
2024-06-22T00:41:49.965Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [level]                 
2024-06-22T00:41:49.965Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
2024-06-22T00:41:49.965Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
2024-06-22T00:41:49.965Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
2024-06-22T00:41:49.965Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [msg]                                
2024-06-22T00:41:49.965Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
2024-06-22T00:41:49.965Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [n]             
2024-06-22T00:41:49.966Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
2024-06-22T00:41:51.876Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [p]
2024-06-22T00:41:51.876Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [p] starting at position 4 in conversion pattern.
2024-06-22T00:41:51.877Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [d]
2024-06-22T00:41:51.877Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 21 in conversion pattern.
2024-06-22T00:41:51.877Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [C]                                 
2024-06-22T00:41:51.877Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [C] starting at position 27 in conversion pattern.                        
2024-06-22T00:41:51.877Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [m]
2024-06-22T00:41:51.877Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [m] starting at position 32 in conversion pattern.
2024-06-22T00:41:51.877Z main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [n]
2024-06-22T00:41:51.877Z main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.

Extract from relevant maven pom:
plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-transform-maven-shade-plugin-extensions</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>package-jar</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <configuration>
        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
        <artifactSet>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>org.broadinstitute.gatk:gsalib:tar.gz:*</exclude>
            <exclude>org.broadinstitute.gatk:*:tar.bz2:example-resources</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </artifactSet>
        <filters>
          <filter>
            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor</exclude>
              <exclude>**/Log4j2Plugins.dat</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </filter>
        </filters>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.logging.log4j.maven.plugins.shade.transformer.Log4j2PluginCacheFileTransformer"/>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <manifestEntries>
              <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
              <Main-Class>${app.main.class}</Main-Class>
            </manifestEntries>
          </transformer>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
            <resource>${resource.bundle.path}</resource>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>


Share the log4j3 configuration.

Non provided.... I looked into the jar file and there is no log4j* files only excption is old log4j.dtd file (old dangling log4j 1.2.x dependency) that I plan to strip out from the build but otherwise the app is running log4j2 only.

Sorry I mistyped. What is the log4j2.xml or log4j2.properties used by the application?

Is all selftcontained in a jar file. the workdir does not contain any files and the user home does not contain any log4j config files either.

Provide a [mre].

@aled understand the request but is one of those that are rather difficult. This is a large build of a private commercial repo that I'm not allowed to share.... I guess what I'm asking for is some pointer as to where that conflicting configuration may be coming from knowing that we lack log4jX configuration files.

I understand but If you can not provide details then it is not a good question for [so]. There are several answers in the other question. Have you tried them all?

Also ... if this is a large commercial application, you should approach the vendor for support questions.

@StephenC is my companies so we are the vendors. This a minor bug that I would like to fix.

In the end I found the culprit in my case so I'm posting in case it helps someone else issue; since these messages seem to be most of the time due to the multiple Log4j2Plugins.dat conflict with or without maven involved, is difficult to address possible alternative issues that cause the seem error messages.
In my case the problem was that our build had some optional jar minimization feature on from the maven-shade-plugin:

<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.1</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
      <id>package-jar</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>none</phase>
      <configuration>
        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
        <!-- ... -->
      </configuration>
    </exectuion>
  </executions>
</plugin>  
   

Change the true above for a false was everything that was needed.
That resulted in many classes that are not explicitly referenced in the code to be dropped out from the jar including classes under org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.**. So the core supporting plugging/pattern were not loaded resulting in the init ERROR messages.
log4j-core's logger (StatusLogger) would output INFO messages when such plugins were referenced within Log4j2Plugins.dat which by default is not output in my case thus silencing the cause of the issue. I guess I could have avoided expending as much time as I did figuring it out if I had change the StatusLogger output level but perhaps a WARNING rather than INFO makes more sense (jar minimizers should then have the option to explicitly opt out).


But the problem persist even after implementing both solutions described in the answer to that question.

Those solutions are mutually exclusive:

removing Log4j2Plugins.dat forces Log4j to do a time-consuming classpath scan of the org.apache.logging.log4j package. This feature will be disabled in a future release,
the Log4j2PluginCacheFileTransformer on the other hand is a proper solution, since it merges all Log4j2Plugins.dat files into one.

Remove the exclusion of Log4j2Plugins.dat files and your application should work.
Remark: Due to a bug (see Issue #87), the transformer does not work properly if a single Log4j2Plugins.dat file is present in your dependencies. This will be fixed in version 0.1.1.

@PiotrPKarwasz thanks, will try. If having that .dat file in the jar is so beneficial what is the tool that is suppose to generate it in a maven environment.  Asking just in case you know it of your head

The file is present in log4j-core.jar and every JAR containing extensions (e.g. log4j-layout-template-json.jar). The problem is not how to generate the file, but how to properly merge two such files. If you have multiple plugin caches and you just randomly choose a Log4j2Plugins.dat file and discard the rest (this is what Maven Shade Plugin does by default), you'll end up loosing Log4j plugins, in your case the DateConverter (responsible for %d).

I have tried without the exclusion and no success. After trying a few more things I saw this other workaround described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75996306/log4j2-dynamic-appender-doesnt-work-with-maven-shade-pluginin where you basically pick the Log4j2Plugins.dat from log4j-core and put it in the same location under META-INF.... in my packaged/shaded .jar and still does not work!!!! what is going on?

Debugging at this point and actually the .dat file gets read/parsed in despite then if fails. I've got it from log4j-core.jar so is rather strange. will keep debugging.

Finally! my pom has some jar minimization set up at packaging that was getting rid of "unused" classes, which include several if not all under org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.*.  The StatusLogger (log4j "internal logger" spit messages indicating the missing classes only at the info level. Had it make spit messages at debug I would have seen them.
